# Redshift Postgres SQL comparing NULL vs NOT NULL values in a table

Tags: postgresql, null

I am trying to create a query in Redshift DB (Postgres SQL) to do the following:

I have columns that I am checking for quality control and need the percentages of `NULL` vs. `NOT NULL` for each column. I would like my output to look like this, below shows the totals but need it in `%` if possible.  How can I write this query?

```
Column     NOT NULL  NULL       Total Records           Percentage NULL   
--------- -------   ------    ----------------        ---------------------
Column A     78       10            88                       11.3%
Column B     68       15            83                       18.0%
Column C      3        5             8                       62.5%
```

Comment: [Comparison operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-comparison.html) and I assume percentage calculations are not an issue. If there is a specific question, do edit it in. As such this question is too broad.

Comment: I have edited my request and hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQL, you can calculate the values for a specific column, like this:

```
select
  count(a) as "NOT_NULL",
  count(*) - count(a) as "NULL",
  count(*) as "Total Records",
  to_char(100.0 * (count(*) - count(a)) / count(*), '999.9%') as "Percentage NULL"
from stack
```

However, it is not possible to display "one row per column". You would have to `JOIN` several queries together to produce that result.